# Python prime nos_ "or" operator issue

Tags: python

```
n = input("enter the no: ")
def prime():
    global count
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if n==0 or n==1:
            print "it is not prime"            
        elif i==0 or i==1:
            pass       
        elif n%i==0:
            count+=1
    return count
prime()
if count>0:
    print "not prime"
else:
    print "it is prime"
```

i am trying to find a given no is prime or not. I am having issue with the number 0 and 1. For "0" i am getting result as "it is prime". for "1", i am getting the result as "it is not prime" and "it is prime". I tried using "in" operator instead of "or". But i am getting the same result. Please let me know where am i wrong?

Comment: I remember that you asked this earlier. Instead of repeating your question, go through the code and carry out its statements by hand, and you'll probably find the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comment.

Answer (score -1):

When you enter '0' range(n) returns empty list. So It is giving you 0 is prime.
Try this code:

```
n = input("enter the no: ")
def prime():
    global count
    count = 0
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        count = 1
    for i in range(n):
        if i==0 or i==1:
            count = 1
        elif n%i==0:
            count+=1
    return count
prime()
if count>0:
    print "not prime"
else:
    print "it is prime"
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code is perfect except it should not be count=1 when i==0 or i==1 since the divisor cannot be 0 or 1.

Comment: Ohhh Yeah you are crct. Tnq :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the global variable count, you dont have to return it. The code can be made cleaner if you start the loop from 1.

So for a prime number, it would have only one factor (the number 1).

```
n = int(raw_input("enter the no: "))
count = 0
def prime():
    global count
    global n
    count = 0
    for i in range(1,n):           
        if n%i==0:
            count+=1

prime()
if count==1:
    print "It is prime"
else:
    print "Not prime"
```